# Can a vector space over an infinite field be a finite union of proper subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space ever be a finite union of proper subspaces?

If the ground field is finite, then any finite-dimensional vector space is finite as a set, so there are a finite number of 1-dimensional subspaces, and it is the union of those. So let's assume the ground field is infinite.

Comment: Very  interesting question.If I remember correctly  a related    problem is given in  the book of  Herstein, Topics  in algebra.

Comment: @AliTaghavi It is a question in M. Artin's Algebra.

Comment: Related thread in [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60698/11619).

Comment: Fun fact: From this, it easily follows that for $|k| = \infty$ and $k$-algebras $R$, the Prime Avoidance Lemma holds for arbitrary ideals. I.e. for ideals $J, I_1, \dots, I_n \subsetneq R$ with $J \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i$ we get $J \subseteq I_i$ for some $i$.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can prove by induction on n that:

An affine space over an infinite field $F$ is not the union of $n$ proper *affine* subspaces.

The inductive step goes like this: Pick one of the affine subspaces $V$. Pick an affine subspace of codimension one which contains it, $W$. Look at all the translates of $W$. Since $F$ is infinite, some translate $W'$ of $W$ is not on your list. Now restrict all other subspaces down to $W'$ and apply the inductive hypothesis.

This gives the tight bound that an $F$ affine space is not the union of $n$ proper subspaces if $|F|>n$. For vector spaces, one can get the tight bound $|F|\geq n$ by doing the first step and then applying the affine bound.

Answer (score 89):

Let $V$ be the union $\cup_{i=1}^n V_i$, where the $V_i$ are proper subspaces and the ground field $k$ is infinite.  Pick a non-zero vector $x\in V_1$.  Pick $y\in V-V_1$, and note that there are infinitely many vectors of the form $x+\alpha y$, with $\alpha\in k^\ast$. Now $x+\alpha y$ is never in $V_1$, and so there is some $V_j$, $j\neq 1$, with infinitely many of these vectors, so it contains $y$, and thus contains $x$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we see $V_1$ is contained in $\cup_{i=2}^n V_i$; clearly this process can be repeated to find a contradiction.

Steve

Comment: +1.  Short and self-contained.  I really liked it!

Comment: best proof and shortest one 



Comment: Similar technique can be found in the proof of the fact that 'A finite extension is simple iff there exist only finitely many immediate subfields'

Comment: With this proof we can even get the sufficient bound $|k|\geq n$: If this condition is met, then by the pigeonhole principle some $V_i$ with $i\neq 1$ must contain two different linear combinations of $x$ and $y$, which assures that $x\in V_i$.

Comment: Should be $|k|>n$ in my previous comment (to take into account the case $\alpha=0$).

Comment: From $x+\alpha y \in V_j$, how can you conclude that $y \in V_j$? Can you please explain it. I couldn't understand.

Comment: It's enough that $x + \alpha y \in V_j$ for at least two different values of $\alpha$, say for $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$. Then $(x + \alpha_1 y) - (x + \alpha_2 y) \in V_j$, implying that $y \in V_j$.

Comment: what is meant by V - V_1? V without V_1?

Comment: Also what is $k^*$ ?

Comment: Yes, the minus denotes a set-theoretic complement here. The $k^*$ (I personally prefer $k^\times$) denotes the units of a ring $k$, in this case actually all the nonzero elements since our $k$ is a field.

Comment: Can someone tell me what exactly the contradiction is here? I think that if $V_1\subseteq V_2 \cup\cdots\cup V_n$. Then $V=V_2 \cup\cdots\cup V_n$ contradicting the minimality of $n$, right?

Comment: @Hopmaths, continue this process until there is only one subspace remaining --- a contradiction.

Answer (score 13):

I recently completed a short expository note on this subject, *Covering Numbers in Linear Algebra*.  See:

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/coveringnumbersv2.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/coveringnumbersv2.pdf)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing this.  It was a treat to read.

Comment: broken  link.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a reduction to the finite dimensional case.  Let $F$ be a finite set of subspaces of $X$.  For each finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$, let $u(Y)$ be the set of elements $Z$ of $F$ such that $Y$ is contained in $Z$.  By assumption, $u(Y)$ is non-empty for every $Y$.  Since any two finite dimensional subspaces are contained in a third, the intersection of the sets $u(Y)$, as $Y$ runs among all finite dimensional subspaces of $X$, is non-empty.  Hence there is at least one set in $F$ that contains every finite dimensional subspace of $X$, hence contains $X$.

For the finite dimensional case, let $F$ be a finite set of subspaces of $X$.  By induction, every codimension 1 subspace of $X$ is contained in some $Y$ from $F$.  But there are infinitely many codimension $1$ subspaces, so some $Y$ in $F$ contains more than one such subspace.  Any two distinct codimension 1 subspaces $\operatorname{span} X$ (if $\dim X > 1$) so $Y = X$.

Comment: Very nice. For any future reader who gets confused in the same way I did, the assumption in the sentence "By assumption, u(Y) is non-empty for every Y" is the finite-dimensional case.

Answer (score 4):

[Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko)'s comment prompted me to write a new version of this short answer. I'm leaving the old version to make Anton's comment clearer (and also to increase the probability of having at least one correct answer).

**NEW VERSION.** Let $A$ be an affine space over an infinite field $K$, and let $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be nonzero $K$-valued functions on $A$ which are polynomial on each (affine) line. Then the product of the $f_i$ is nonzero. In particular the $f_i^{-1}(0)$ do **not** cover $A$.

Indeed, as pointed out by Anton, the $K$-valued functions on $A$ which are polynomial on each line form obviously a ring $R$. This ring is a domain, because if $f$ and $g$ are nonzero elements of $R$, then there is a line on which none of them is zero, and their product is nonzero on this line.

**OLD VERSION.** Let $A$ be an affine space over an infinite field $K$, and let $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be nonzero $K$-valued functions on $A$ which are polynomial on each finite dimensional affine subspace. Then the product of the $f_i$ is nonzero. In particular the $f_i^{-1}(0)$ do **not** cover $A$.

Indeed, we can assume that $A$ is finite dimensional, in which case the result is easy and well known.

Comment: Ahhh +1. It took me a while to understand what's going on here. The confusing statement was *"the product of the $f_i$ is nonzero"*. Here's my expansion of that statement. (1) The set of functions which are polynomial on each finite-dimensional subspace is clearly a ring. (2) Given two non-zero functions of this form, there is a finite-dimensional subspace on which they are *both* non-zero (a 2-dimensional subspace spanned by two points witnessing the non-zero-ness of the two functions will do). (3) By (2) and the finite-dimensional case, the ring is an integral domain.

Comment: @Anton Geraschenko - Thanks for your vote and your comment, so much clearer than my answer!

Answer (score 3):

I needed this result for a paper I wrote with David Leep ten years ago. Bruce Reznick came up with a nice proof which we included in the paper (Marriage, Magic, and Solitaire, published in the American Math Monthly). I don't think the proof was any better than the ones already given here, and I seriously doubt this was the first time a proof had ever appeared in print, but I wonder if anyone knows an earlier citation.

Comment: Well, this is Thm 1.2 in Roman's book Advanced Linear Algebra. I have the 3rd edition from 2008. The 1st edition is from 1993; I don't know if it was in there. He doesn't cite anything. 

Comment: I believe it is one of those problems that turns up again and again over the years.  I have seen it posed at least once as a problem in the American Mathematical Monthly (unfortunately I don't remember when, even up to a decade, and I don't know of a good way to search for it), but my guess is that its provenance dates back from well before 1993.

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly worse answer for the fin dim case  - prove the following - if k is an infinite field then if f is a polynomial in n variables over k there exists a point of k^n x such that f(x) is non zero (proving this really isn't much easier than the actual problem though - I told you it was a worse answer.) Each  subspace is mapped to zero by some poly over k, multiplying the polys gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response to the post, but I noticed that the question was not answered in general.

> No vector space is the finite union of proper subspaces.

EDIT: In response to my false solution, Phil Hartwig pointed out that $\mathbb{F}$$_{2}^2$ is a vector space that is the union of three proper subspaces. Indeed, the "routine" induction was less routine and more nonsensical. I had fixed my proof, only to realize that my solution was much less elegant than Halmos' solution found in his Linear Algebra Problem Book. You can view the page [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=DQP3AIlrCP0C&lpg=PA211&dq=No%2520vector%2520space%2520over%2520an%2520infinite%2520field%2520is%2520a%2520finite%2520union%2520of%2520proper%2520subspaces&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In the class of Banach spaces there is a stronger result:

> If $B$ is a Banach space, then $B$ is not the *countable* union of proper subspaces.

This relies on the fact that a proper subspace of a topological vector space has empty interior. To appeal to your intuition in $\mathbb{R}^3$, every proper subspace (a plane or line through the origin) cannot completely contain an open ball (an open set in the usual norm topology).

Since $B$ is complete (by definition), by Baire's Theorem it is not the countable union of nowhere dense sets. Since proper subspaces are nowhere dense, $B$ is not the countable union of proper subspaces.

Comment: The "routine induction" doesn't work. As Anton already noted in his initial post $(\mathbb{F}_2)^2=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}\cup \{(0,0),(0,1)\}\cup \{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: @Philipp: Under the assumption the OP gave that the field is infinite, your counterexample does not hold.

Comment: Where is the assumption that the field is infinite used?

Comment: Thanks Phillip for pointing out my mistake. I have revised my post accordingly and have provided a link to a very elegant answer. 

Comment: The proof in Halmos’ book seems to be the same as the one posted above by Steve D.

Comment: A vector space $V$ of dimension infinite is always union of a countable
set of proper subspaces.

Take a Hamel basis  $e_\alpha$ . Each vector can be written 
$v = \sum_\alpha x_\alpha e_\alpha$.  

Let $V_\alpha$ the subspace of those vectors for which $x_\alpha = 0$

It is clear that $V$ is the union of any sequence $V_{\alpha_n}$
for $n\in \N$  with  $\alpha_n$ differents.

Comment: @juan: That's only true for a vector space with countable dimension.

Comment: @Adam: proper subspaces of a Banach space can be dense.

Comment: What I said is true for any infinite dimension. I speak about a Hamel basis. Each vector has only a finite number of non null coordinates.

Comment: Hence any Banach space of dimension infinite is the union of a countable set of hyperplanes.

Baire theorem is no problem since an hyperplane may be of second Baire category.

In fact there was a conjecture by Klee and Wilansky that  first category hyperplane are the same as closed hyperplanes. I proved this conjecture is not true

Dense Hyperplanes of First Category. Mathematische Annalen. Vol. 249. 1980. Pag. 111-114. 

Comment: @George. It depends on what one means by a subspace. 

Functional analysts use the word subspace in infinite dimensional space synonymously with the term "closed subspace". The term "linear manifold" is used for a not-necessarily closed subspace. 

For example, the set of all sequences in $\ell^2$ with finitely many non-zero coordinates is a dense linear manifold in $\ell^2$, but not a dense subspace. It's semantics, really, but I wanted to clear up what I meant in the original post.
 

Comment: @juan See my comment in response to George. The "subspaces" you're constructing are not what I mean by "subspace". The notation is unfortunate, so I regret any confusion that I've caused.

It is certainly true that no proper closed subspace has interior in the norm topology. For if it did contain an open ball, one could shift it to the origin and take successive dilations (which would be elements of the subspace) to exhaust the entire space. 


Comment: @Adam Azzam I can cite many many papers on Functional Analysis that uses subspaces in his usual sense. And always says closed subspace 
when this is the intended meaning. 

Your remarked phrase is false. You may put it as 

If B is a Banach space, then B is not the countable union of proper closed subspaces.

This is true and you must correct. In the proof you also must put the adjective closed where this is your meaning. 

Answer (score -6):

The finite dimensional case cannot happen by dimension counting (just view everything as affine spaces).

Comment: This argument certainly doesn't suffice by itself; it doesn't explain where the infinitude of the field comes into play. 