# Originality of an idea

Tags: soft-question, bibliography

How can I verify (ensure myself) that a research question in mathematics was not already treated ?

or at least see where a particular paper was cited ?

thank you.

PS : I hope i am posting in the right section and forum (please redirect me if iam not)

Comment: Is this question about research in mathematics?  You do not say so. But perhaps this was assumed as implicitly clear. Anyway, it is better to be explicit and if possible you might narrow the subject even a a bit more as it can play a role. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: To find where a paper was cited there are lots of resources; MathSciNet has a citation search, for example; Scopus also does forward citation searches. If you have a local university/math library, they can probably help you with resources to do forward citation searches. You can also talk to people who work in the field.

Comment: Google Scholar also gives citations.

Comment: to quid thanks. edit done. Thank you to Arturo Magidin. Effectively it is in mathematics.

A part, checking citations and talking to expert in the fields, is there any other way that is common to mathematician and that i dont know?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The two you name are the main ways in my opinion. You can present it at a conference or in a seminar  (though this is subsumed under talking to experts in a way). You can also post a preprint to arXiv before you submit and wait a bit, if it is known somebody might point it  out. A further check will be the referee (and the editor) at the journal.

Comment: If you are sufficiently careful, you can submit a reference request on MathOverflow on your question.  quid's answer to http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1516 is good: the main point (in my view) is to convince the community that you have done some work trying to find out, and that you would like some help without the community doing a lot of work for you.  Search meta.mathoverflow.net for other information on asking such kinds of questions.  Gerhard "Helps Literature Searches, Not Replaces" Paseman, 2015.10.12

Comment: Thanks you quid and Gerhard Paseman for your interests. Another idea that i have just thought about is to proceed to a research via key-words. Is it possible to make this on scopus or mathscinet (i have not the access now in home) ?

Comment: This question is basically asking "How do I do a literature search", so: Possible duplicate of [Strategies for digging through literature](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46417/strategies-for-digging-through-literature)