# How hard must "no high-degree irreducibles" proofs be?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, asymptotics, fields

Let $\mathsf{RCF}$ be the usual theory of real closed fields and for $n>2$ let $\theta_n$ be the sentence "No degree-$n$ polynomial is irreducible." Since $\mathsf{RCF}$ is complete, for every $n$ we have $\mathsf{RCF}\vdash\theta_n$. I'm curious how hard it must be to prove $\theta_n$, as a function of $n$.

One way to formalize this is the following. Let $\mathsf{RCF}_k$ be the (finitely axiomatizable!) subtheory of $\mathsf{RCF}$ gotten by restricting attention to polynomials of degree $\le k$. Then we can ask:

> What is the growth rate of the function $$\mathfrak{F}:\mathbb{N}_{>2}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}:n\mapsto\min\{k:\mathsf{RCF}_k\vdash\theta_n\}$$ sending each degree above $2$ to the highest degree we need to consider?

I'm also interested in the qualitative question, "As $n$ increases, does $\theta_n$ get meaningfully harder to prove or does the same basic strategy work for all $n$?," but I'm a bit skeptical that that's sufficiently clear to have a good answer. I'd also be interested in questions about proof *length* (measured either in symbols or in steps), but there I'm skeptical that there is much that's easy to say (questions about proof length tend to get hairy, in my admittedly-limited experience).

---

To clarify, the axiomatization I have in mind is the conjunction of

- the field axioms,
- the assertion that the relation "$b-a$ has a square root" is a compatible ordering, and
- for each $n$ the assertion that every degree-$n$ polynomial satisfies the intermediate value theorem.

Only this last clause is affected by the $\mathsf{RCF}\leadsto\mathsf{RCF}_k$ truncation.

Comment: The argument in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#By_Induction gives a simple upper bound: $F(n)\le$ the first odd number in the sequence $n_0=n$, $n_{i+1}=\binom{n_i}2$.

Comment: The optimal bound should probably follow from Galois-theoretic methods as in Shipman, *Improving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks! I wasn't aware of Shipman's article at all - it's fantastic! (To save others from googling, it's available [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02986170).)

Comment: An explicit upper bound is $F(n)\le\frac{n!}{2^{v_2(n!)}}\le\frac{(n+1)!}{2^n}$. Let $R\models\mathrm{RCF}_k$ with $k$ as indicated, $f\in R[x]$ be irreducible of degree $n$, $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $R$, $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K/R)$, $P\le G$ be a Sylow $2$-group, and $R\subseteq L\subseteq K$ a field such that $\mathrm{Gal}(K/L)=P$. Since $G$ embeds in $S_n$, we have $|G|\mid n!$, hence $[L:R]=[G:P]\mid k$. Since $L/R$ is simple by Artin's theorem, there is an irreducible polynomial of odd degree $[L:R]$, contradicting IVT unless $[L:R]=1$. Thus, $[K:R]$ is a power of $2$, and ...

Comment: ... so is $[K(i):R(i)]$. Since any nontrivial $2$-group has an index-$2$ subgroup, $K(i)$ includes a degree $2$ extension of $R(i)$ unless $K(i)=R(i)$. But already $\mathrm{RCF}_1$ implies that all quadratic polynomials over $R(i)$ have roots, hence this is impossible. Thus, $K\subseteq R(i)$ has degree at most $2$ over $R$, i.e., $n\le2$. Note that this argument does not need the full power of IVT, only its corollary that any polynomial of odd degree $\le k$ has a root.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Nice! If you turn that into an answer, I'll upvote it - that's definitely more than I knew before.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t know how to make use of the full power of the intermediate value theorem, hence I will work instead with a weaker axiomatization: let $\def\rcf{\mathrm{RCF}}\rcf'_k$ denote the first two groups of axioms from the question (i.e., $\rcf_1$) + the assertion that every polynomial of odd degree $d\le k$ has a root, and let
$$\def\fF{\mathfrak F}\fF'(n)=\min\{k:\rcf'_k\vdash\theta_n\},\quad n>2.$$
Since $\rcf_k\vdash\rcf'_k$, we have $\fF(n)\le\fF'(n)$. (On the other hand, $\bigwedge_{n=3}^k\theta_n$ implies $\rcf_k$ over $\rcf_1$, hence $\rcf'_{\max\{\fF'(n):3\le n\le k\}}\vdash\rcf_k$. I don’t know if one can do better.)

I claim that if $n$ is not a power of $2$, then
$$\fF(n)\le\fF'(n)\le\binom n{n_2},\quad\text{where }n_2=2^{v_2(n)}$$
(i.e., $n_2$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $n$). Note that $\binom n{n_2}$ is odd (see e.g. [Kummer’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem)).

To see this, let $R\models\rcf'_k$ for $k=\binom n{n_2}$, and assume for contradiction that $f\in R[x]$ of degree $n$ is irreducible. Let $\{\alpha_i:i\in[n]\}$ list the roots of $f$ in a fixed splitting field of $f$ over $R$.

For any symmetric polynomial $s\in R[x_1,\dots,x_{n_2}]$, the coefficients of
$$p_s(x)=\prod_{i_1<\dots<i_{n_2}}(x-s(\alpha_{i_1},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n_2}}))$$
are symmetric polynomials in the $\alpha_i$’s, hence $p_s\in R[x]$. Since $p_s$ has degree $k$, it has a root in $R$: i.e., there is $\{i_1,\dots,i_{n_2}\}\subseteq[n]$ such that
$$s(\alpha_{i_1},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n_2}})\in R.$$

Let $\{\sigma_t:t\le n_2\}$ denote the elementary symmetric polynomials in $n_2$ variables. For each $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_{n_2}\}\subseteq[n]$, $i_1<\dots<i_{n_2}$, the set
$$V_I=\bigl\{(r_1,\dots,r_{n_2})\in R^{n_2}:\textstyle\sum_tr_t\sigma_t(\alpha_{i_1},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n_2}})\in R\bigr\}$$
is an $R$-linear space, and by what we have just proved above,
$$R^{n_2}=\bigcup_{\substack{I\subseteq[n]\\|I|=n_2}}V_I.$$
Since a linear space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces (see e.g. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces)), there is $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_{n_2}\}$ such that $V_I=R^{n_2}$. That is, $\sigma_t(\alpha_{i_1},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n_2}})\in R$ for all $t=1,\dots,n$, which means that
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n_2}(x-\alpha_{i_j})\in R[x],$$
contradicting the irreducibility of $f$ (as $n_2<n$ by assumption).

Note that what we have really shown is that $\rcf'_k$ proves that every polynomial of degree $n$ has a factor of degree $n_2$.

---

What about the case when $n$ *is* a power of $2$? In the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422793/how-hard-must-no-high-degree-irreducibles-proofs-be?noredirect=1#comment1086574_422793), I gave an argument that
$$\fF'(n)\le\frac{n!}{2^{v_2(n!)}}=\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}},$$
but this is considerably larger than the bound in the non-power-of-$2$ case. Let me outline how to prove an asymptotically better bound
$$\fF'(n)\le\binom{\binom n{n/2}}2.$$

Let $\def\acf{\mathrm{ACF}}\acf_k$ denote the theory of fields such that every polynomial of degree $2$ or of odd degree $d\le k$ has a root.

If $R\models\rcf'_{\binom{2k}2}$ then $R(i)\models\acf_k$: $\rcf'_1$ already implies that $R(i)$ is quadratically closed, and if $f\in R(i)[x]$ is a degree-$d$ polynomial with $d$ odd, then $f\overline f\in R[x]$ has degree $2d$, hence as we have shown, $\rcf'_{\binom{2d}2}$ ensures that it has a quadratic factor in $R[x]$, hence a root in $R(i)$.

By the same reasoning as above, $\acf_{\binom n{n_2}}$ proves that any degree-$n$ polynomial has a degree-$n_2$ factor. In particular, if $n\equiv2\pmod4$, then $\acf_{\binom n2}$ proves that any degree-$n$ polynomial has a root.

If $n$ is a power of $2$, then $\acf_{\binom{\binom n{n/2}}2}$ proves that any polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ has a factor of degree $n/2$, hence, by induction on $n$, it proves that any such polynomial has a root: we do the construction above with $n/2$ in place of $n_2$; since $\binom n{n/2}\equiv2\pmod4$, all the degree-$\binom n{n/2}$ polynomials considered have roots by the previous paragraph.

Now, let $n\ge4$ be a power of $2$, and $f\in R[x]$ of degree $n$, where $R\models\rcf'_{\binom{\binom n{n/2}}2}$. Doing again the symmetric polynomial construction with $n/2$ in place of $n_2$, each of the relevant degree-$\binom n{n/2}$ polynomials has a quadratic factor over $R$, hence a root in $R(i)$. In this way, we find a degree-$n/2$ polynomial $g\in R(i)[x]$ such that $g\mid f$. Since $2\binom{\binom{n/2}{n/4}}2\le\binom n{n/2}$, we have $R(i)\models\acf_{\binom{\binom{n/2}{n/4}}2}$, thus by the previous paragraph, $g$ has a root in $R(i)$, hence $f$ has a root or a quadratic factor over $R$.